# Traversing TreeNodes to find the highest level parents Tag data, how to save initial TreeNodes info?

Tags: c#, forms, treeview

I have `TreeNode` object from my `TreeView` which is the currently selected Node. I would like to traverse this node to find its highest level parent and get some information from it (namely the data in its `Tag` variable).

How could I easily do this while keeping my `inNode` still equal to what it was then the function was passed it?

```
private void openNodeWindow(TreeNode inNode)
{
    // Find the top level window type this is in.
    TreeNode curNode = inNode; 
    WindowType topLevelType = WindowType.NO_WINDOW;

    // As long as there is a parent to this Node
    while (curNode.Parent != null && 
        // As long as that parent has a specified window type
        (WindowType)curNode.Parent.Tag != WindowType.NO_WINDOW)
    {
        topLevelType = (WindowType)curNode.Tag;
        curNode = curNode.Parent;
    }

    // Do stuff with the topLevelType variable now
    // Also having inNode set back to what it was originally
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Clone the object instead of setting a reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.clone(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// TreeNode curNode = inNode; // set by reference
TreeNode curNode = (TreeNode) inNode.Clone(); // clone (set by value)
```

Now when you modify the curNode object, the inNode should be unmodified.

**EDIT** this only seems to be shallow copy.

> (from msdn TreeNode.Clone Method)
>
> Remarks: The tree structure from the tree node being cloned and below
>   is copied. Any child tree nodes assigned to the TreeNode being cloned
>   are included in the new tree node and subtree.
>
> The Clone method
>   performs a shallow copy of the node. If the value of the Tag property
>   is a reference type, both the original and cloned copy will point to
>   the same single instance of the Tag value.

You could try to make a deep copy of the object, more reference of how here.

- [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)
- [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

Or you could 'backup' the values you want to preserve and copy them back to the inNode object when you are done using curNode

Comment: This does not preserve the "graph" that the nodes make up. I cannot traverse `curNode` the same (or at all) like I would `inNode`. The parent of `curNode` is `null` when made in that manner.

Comment: @user1596244 Ok, the clone didn't worked as I though i would then. The idea is the same. You make 'backup' of the values and use them later.

Comment: I have found a sneaky way around my problem. I just call `TreeView.GetSelectedNode` twice in my function, once to work on it as above, the second to use it later on. I just let the treeview do the work for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: -1 this shouldn't be marked as an answer as it's completely different from what the op is asking.  Also, the example links are for deep cloning of objects, not cloning a TreeNode hierarchy.